# ssl version or cipher mismatch ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, certificate

I have a problem with https in express and I don't really understand it:

**This is from my last project (it works):**

index.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/server.cert', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80);
httpsServer.listen(443);

//Force https
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
  }
  next();
});
```

**This is from my current project (doesn't work):**

index.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

 var configRaw = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/config.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
     if(err) {
         return abort('Can not read/ find' + __dirname + '/config.json'); //FIXME
     }
 });

 var config = JSON.parse(configRaw);

 console.log('  - loading webserver script..');
 var webServer = require(__dirname + '/lib/web_server.js');

 webServer.init(config.httpPort, config.httpsPort);
```

web_server.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/server.cert', 'utf8');

var credential = { key: privateKey, vert: certificate };
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credential, app);

this.init = function(httpPort, httpsPort){
   httpServer.listen(httpPort);
   httpsServer.listen(httpsPort);
}

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
if(!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
}
   next();  
});
```

I am using the same certificate and key as before and never got an fs-error while reading a file or something.

But when I go to localhost via the browser I get this message: *ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH*.

Please keep in mind that I am fairly new to Node.js - thank you very much in advance! ;)

Comment: Does your real code really have `vert: certificate` instead of `cert: certificate`?

Comment: Note to self: need more sleep! - Thank you very much though! I almost lost my mind over this. ;) (Answer so I can accept!)

Comment: I'm amazed how stack overflow is able to find someone who has the same typos as you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you've got a typo:

```
var credential = { key: privateKey, vert: certificate };
```

"vert" instead of "cert" :)